# How can I invoke the MySQL interactive client from PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, shell, system

I'm trying to get

```
`mysql -uroot`;
```

to enter the MySQL interactive client just as executing

```
$ mysql -uroot
```

from the shell does.

It's okay if the PHP script exists after (or before), but I need it to invoke the MySQL client.

I've tried using proc_open() and of course system(), exec() and passthru(). Wondering if anyone has any tips.

Comment: are you getting any errors? Also, you know is supposed to be `mysql -u root` with the space between `-u` and `root`?

Comment: @Dirk: It does work also with -uroot

Comment: It works without the space too. When the credentials are incorrect, I'll get the mysql connection error. But if they're correct, it'll just hang and I'll have to break out of it with Ctrl-C.

Comment: why exactly are you trying to invoke an interactive client from php?

Comment: See my comments to @Javier's answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

New solution:

```
<?php
$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => STDIN,
   1 => STDOUT,
   2 => STDERR
);
$process = proc_open('mysql -uroot', $descriptorspec, $pipes);
```

---

Old one:

Save for tab completion (you could probably get it in there if you read out bytes with fread instead of using fgets), this gets you on your way, lots left to tweak:

```
<?php
$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pty"),
   1 => array("pty"),
   2 => array("pty")
);
$process = proc_open('mysql -uroot', $descriptorspec, $pipes);
stream_set_blocking($pipes[1], 0);
stream_set_blocking($pipes[2], 0);
stream_set_blocking(STDIN,0);
do {
   echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
   echo stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
   while($in = fgets(STDIN)) fwrite($pipes[0],$in);
} while (1);
```

Comment: Very nice approach, only a note, I tried it both on Linux and on Mac, but it does not work under Mac OSX. It will give me a `pty pseudo terminal not supported on this system` warning.

Comment: See the update, maybe that works (there's a reason why `pty` & direct streams are not documented, but more or less supported on linux).

Comment: I updated your answer with a full working solution even on mac. With this one even the readline library is working, so I can use backspace and arrow keys. Well done.

Comment: @Wrikken: Forget about my edit, I haven't understood your second approach. Following lines are not needed on Mac, it does work without them.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it does work, but it's waiting for some input.  Try sending some sql commands to it's `stdin`.  Of course, since the backtick operator doesn't support IO remapping, you'll need more complex process handling.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not useful to me. I'm not trying to interact with the CLI programmatically. I'm trying to use it as a shortcut. I can invoke it with a BASH script, but I don't want to use BASH this time because I'm building a PHP-based CLI interface, where all commands go through a common place. By executing it in BASH, it'll break that consistency.

Comment: I don't get it.  you want to invoke `mysql` but not give it any input?

Comment: Most web projects have separate connection credentials and connect to different databases (even within the same project but on different environments). I want to log into the database by typing "db" in the shell in any of my projects and have the proper credentials supplied. I want to automate connecting to the database.